# my If Else condition not working properly in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I am saving a record on button click but it always throwing an error.

I am including an if else condition. I have surpassed all the conditions but still my code is going to the if condition but It should not go to if condition.

code is -

my this.state.question.options value is -

```
[
    {
        id:3250,
        label:'good answer',
        assert:1
        position:1
    },
    {
        id:3249,
        label:'bad answer',
        assert:0
        position:2
    }
]
```

and I am checking if else condition as -

```
if (this.state.question.options.filter(o => o.assert === true).length <= 0) {
    hasError = true
    errorKey = 'add-question-modal-missing-assert-options'
}
else {
    alert("test");
}
```

my code should goto else part and print test as alert but it is going to if part and showing error. Why ?

I wanna show else part i.e test as alert

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: Your array has one value which is an object with 2 keys (`0` and `1`). There is no `assert` key, and definitely not one with a strict value of `true`. Then again, the array is not valid as your string values are not quoted. Please provide an MCVE.

Comment: So how can i do this ? or how can I make array for this filter or how to make filter according to this array ?

Comment: String values are quoted .. I am just giving you the example

Comment: Yeah, so give a decent example. One that doesn't leave us guessing. Having an  array with only one object that has numeric property keys seems weird. A strict comparison to `true` when the occurring `assert` values are `0` and `1` also seems weird.

Comment: Okay i will give you clear object

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check and let me know

Comment: what is this? your object not have true format.

Comment: Check now please

Comment: So, why are you doing a strict comparison to `true` if possible values are `0` and `1`? What are you actually trying to check?

Comment: in assert key there must be one value 0 and another value 1

Comment: `filter` will keep entries for which the callback returns true, in your case all entries for which `assert === true` are kept which is no entries

Answer (score 2):

You are using the strict comparison operator (===) while comparing 2 different values. In your example, 1 is being parsed as an integer, while true is being parsed as a boolean. A strict comparison operator is used to check 2 values on equal values AND equal types.

To fix the error in your code, use a loose comparison (==) or convert the integer to a boolean by using `!!1`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (this.state.question.options.filter((el) => {return !!el.assert}).length <= 0) {
    hasError = true
    errorKey = 'add-question-modal-missing-assert-options'
}
else {
    alert("test");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this.state.question.options value is -

```
[
    {
        id:3250,
        label:'good answer',
        assert:1,
        position:1
    },
    {
        id:3249,
        label:'bad answer',
        assert:0,
        position:2
    }
]
```

and then

```
if (this.state.question.options.filter(o => o.assert == true)).length <= 0) {
    hasError = true
    errorKey = 'add-question-modal-missing-assert-options'
} else {
    alert("test");
}
```

replace `===` strict type with `==`

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, `1` is not strictly equal to `true`. However, it is a good practice to use the strict equality operator `===`.

You should compare `o.assert` with the real possible value `o.assert === 1`.

In terms of readability I would also consider comparing the length to 1 instead of 0:

```
this.state.question.options.filter(option => option.assert === 1).length < 1
```

Answer (score 0):

**Do u want this kind of code**

```
if (this.state.question.options.length <= 0) {
    assert = true;
    hasError = true;
    errorKey = 'add-question-modal-missing-assert-options'
}
else {
    alert("test");
}
```